# c3 time series scatter chart, time data in y axis

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

```
C3 version: 0.4.10:
D3 version: 3.5.5:
Browser: Firefox 55.0.3:
Client OS: Windows 10:
Server OS: CentOS 6:
```

I am working on a C3 time series scatter chart. 
 http://jsfiddle.net/dewanshamsul/f81ymrpc/1/

I want to use time data in the y axis like the following: http://jsfiddle.net/dewanshamsul/t6rtLofc/

But it is not working.  I tried to use

```
y: 'Time',
yFormat: '%H:%M:%S',

axis: {
y: {
    type: 'timeseries',
        tick : {
                format: d3.time.format("%X",)
        },
},
```

I saw one example in R where someone plotted time data in y axis so I was wondering whether it is supported or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jsfiddles that you have provided are identical.
But you may be looking for [axis.rotated](http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-rotated) option.

```
axis: {
    rotated: true,
    y: ...
    x: ...
}
```

[See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/6m1ep54g/1/)

Comment: I am extremely sorry. Somehow I posted the wrong jsfiddle. Please check the updated fiddle now.
http://jsfiddle.net/dewanshamsul/t6rtLofc/6/
I have Date in x axis in the following format 2017-09-05
I have Time in y axis in the following format 13:30:45
Getting to plot the time in y axis is the main issue.

Comment: You have to convert time into *timestamps*, and then set y-axis text formatting: see http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-y-tick-format and https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md

Comment: Also, there are no such option as *data.y* or *data.yFormat*, remove that.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.